# How to access the blade files outside the project directory in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have views folder outside the project directory (let's say I have project in /home/user/laravel-project and views folder in /home/user/view-collection/views). Now the project need to access the blade file.
Adding symlink to the original views location seems to work, but I was trying something like, adding `BLADE_PATH` env and changing the view.php config
view.php

```
'paths' => [
        // resource_path('views'),
        env('BLADE_PATH', resource_path('views'))
    ],
```

.env

```
BLADE_PATH=/home/user/views
```

But this approach is not working.

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: @matiaslauriti, the error says the blade file not found.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Joseph, Yes, but it's not working. I am still trying other alternatives.